# Running several regressions with interaction terms simultaneously in R

Tags: r, regression, tidyverse, interaction

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like the following:

```
yourbehavior  condition  tryreduce  comfortable  vegvalidity
1             2          4          3            3
2             5          7          4            5
3             7          1          2            4
```

I would like to figure out a way to run the following regressions efficiently.

```
lm(yourbehavior ~ condition + tryreduce + (condition*tryreduce), data = df)
lm(yourbehavior ~ condition + comfortable + (condition*comfortable), data = df)
lm(yourbehavior ~ condition + vegvalidity + (condition*vegvalidity), data = df)
```

Does anyone know how I can perform these regression analyses simultaneously? I have several more in my actual dataset than I am including in this example.

I've read that using a for-loop is typically not the most efficient way to conduct these types of analyses in R. If possible, I'd prefer to use the tidyverse since that's what I understand best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, which will create a list where each element is one of the regression models and the name of each list element will be the variable that is interacted with `condition`:

```
library(tidyverse)

interaction.vars = c("tryreduce", "comfortable", "vegvalidity")

form = paste("yourbehavior ~ condition *", interaction.vars)

models = form %>% 
  set_names(interaction.vars) %>% 
  map(~lm(.x, data=df))
```

If you want to iterate over every column except the first two you could do:

```
interaction.vars = names(df)[!names(df) %in% c("yourbehavior","condition")]
```

Note that in a model formula `a*b` is equivalent to `a + b + a*b`, so you don't need to repeat each column name.

for loops aren't necessarily bad, and the `map` function above is essentially iterating in the same way as a for loop. However, many functions in R are [vectorized](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/) which is much faster and more succinct than looping.

Comment: In the last line, with lm(.x, data = df), I am getting the error message that object .x is not found. When I type in "form" instead of ".x", I get "Error: Can't convert a 'lm' object to function".

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to add an `~` before `lm`. That's necessary to tell `map` that an anonymous function is coming. `map` is iterating over each element of `form`. The `.x` tells `map` where that argument goes in the function (in this case `lm`) that you're mapping over.

Comment: What do you mean by an anonymous function? Also, how do I see the full output? When I type "models" or "summary(models)" the output looks different than typical regression output in R and does not include P-values, just coefficients.

Comment: `models` is a list of `lm` objects. To get a full summary of a single `lm` model you would do `summary(m1)` (if your model object is called `m1`).  Here, you need to iterate over the model list, so you could do `map(models, summary)` to get a summary of every model (and the summaries will be returned as a list as well). To get a summary of one specific model, you could do, for example, `summary(models[[2]])` or `summary(models[["comfortable"]])`.

Comment: An `anonymous function` is a function that you create on the fly without giving it a name. See the first couple paragraphs under the "Anonymous Functions" heading [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions) for more info.